# How to run Node.js project connected with MongoDB, { downloaded from GitHub } in my pc

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to know how to run Node.js project connected with MongoDB, { downloaded from GitHub } in my pc

Project link https://github.com/john-smilga/node-express-course/tree/main/06-jobs-api/final

In its read me file it has been written that

````
#### Project Setup

In order to spin up the project, in the root create .env with these two variables, with your own values.

MONGO_URI
JWT_SECRET

After that run this command

```bash
npm install && npm start
```
````

I have installed MongoDB community version, but need help in setting up and run this project[image: this is the error iam getting, after running npm install, run and start]

I want to run this project in my laptop

Comment: did you install dependencies ? `npm install`

Comment: can you post the project url to be able to help you better ?

Comment: Also the code for your `connect.js` file would be benefitial.

Comment: can't find a `.env` file on your file tree. you might need to create the file with your own values

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why.

Comment: @Sou https://github.com/john-smilga/node-express-course/tree/main/06-jobs-api/final

Answer (score 0):

As the readme file suggested you first have to create a `.env` file, then proceed by adding the two required values in your env file:

```
MONGO_URI=your mongo db URI goes here
JWT_SECRET=your JWT Secret token goes here
```

then run `npm i` to install all the required packages and `npm start` to run the project

Answer (score 0):

This project uses the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/john-smilga/node-express-course/blob/dc0635c55bf27ef77a8aeddf3570892480f2c899/06-jobs-api/final/app.js#L1)

https://github.com/john-smilga/node-express-course/blob/dc0635c55bf27ef77a8aeddf3570892480f2c899/06-jobs-api/final/app.js#L55

You can see that the code reads some variable values from a `.env` file. This file is [not pushed](https://github.com/john-smilga/node-express-course/blob/dc0635c55bf27ef77a8aeddf3570892480f2c899/06-jobs-api/final/.gitignore#L2) usually for security issues.

create a file named `.env` at the root of your project. Add two variables:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
JWT_SECRET = <your JWT secret token>
```

Then run again the server  again : `npm start`